# How to extract a package in multiprocessing program

Tags: python, file, multiprocessing, unzip

I'm running into a multiprocessing issue when unzipping a file.

I have a program that uses `SomeClass` in multiple processes. Each process will run `_set_up_package` which extracts the content of some zip file. This zip file only needs to be extracted once and will be used by all processes.

I attempt to only extract the zip file once by:

1. Checking if the file already exists.
2. Creating a threading block as a class variable

This is not working because sometimes I get `FileExistsError` in the program. I thought the class variable lock would be shared by all processes but because I am getting an error I don't believe it is.

How can I unzip a package in a *process-safe* manner?

```
class SomeClass:
    __load_package_lock = threading.RLock()

    def _set_up_package(self):
        self.__load_package_lock.acquire()
        try:
            path_to_zip = os.path.join(self.work_path, "some_zip.zip"
            dest = os.path.join(self.work_path, "some_dest")

            if os.path.isdir(dest):
                return

            with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip, 'r') as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(dest)

        finally:
            self.__load_package_lock.release()
```

Comment: Each process will have its own `SomeClass` and each of those will have its own separate `__load_package_lock` class attribute. You need to pass a `Lock` as an argument to each process. Also, I don't think a `threading.Lock` is the same thing as a `multiprocessing.Lock` — threads and processes are not the same thing.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for pointing that out. I think I has used that when the class was used in a multi-threading application. You're right that the lock doesn't work on a multiprocessing application.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented a solution without using locks.

```
try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(dest)
except FileExistsError:
    self.logger.warning(
        "Un-zipping failed because file already exists: '{0}'".format(path_to_zip))
```